# What is being accessed when converting a pointer to derived class to a pointer to base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

This may be a silly question, but I'm quite confused here... Let there be two classes: `Y` and its base `X`. When we are outside `Y`, we cannot implicitly convert a pointer to `Y` to a pointer to `X` if `X` is a protected or private base of `Y`. If we do that, we would get some error messages like `conversion from 'Y*' to 'X*' exists, but is inaccessible` and `'X' not accessible because 'Y' uses 'private'/'protected' to inherit from 'X'`.

My question is, what actually is inaccessible? What are we actually trying to access here? How is the compiler accessing that behind the scenes so that the access is blocking by the derivation access specifier?

For an extremely simple example:

```cpp
struct X { };

struct Y : protected X { };

int main()
{
    X* p = new Y;
}
```

In my understanding, when we have a `protected`/`private` base, that means the base class facilities inherited to the derived class are treated as `protected`/`private` in the derived class. So, to me, being inaccessible when declaring `X* p = new Y;` means that we are accessing some facility in `Y` inherited from `X` that is treated as `protected`/`private`, I wonder what is that?

Comment: The compiler reads  `protected` or `private` in the inheritance declaration and produces an error message if the code tries to access the base-class (from outside the derived class).  Nothing really clever going on.  If you think there is, please post a [mcve] with some additional detail about the specific problem.

Comment: *"what actually is inaccessible?"* The fact that the classes are drived is not `public`, so it is a "secret" to anyone outside the class. The compiler knows, of course, so can whisper about the secret (but will not let you use it).

Comment: It is the fact that `Y` is derived from `X` that is inaccessible. That is, you're not trying to access a thing that is inherited, you're trying to access the information that the inheritance exists.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks, that's kinda make more sense now...

Comment: Note that you can also tell the compiler to shut up and let you access the base class anyway by using a C-style cast: ```X *p = (X *)(new Y);``` - although you most likely shouldn't do that.

Comment: @JonathanS.     It's certainly not a good idea, unless you like subsequent operations that dereference `p` to have undefined behaviour.

Comment: Follow up from the example:  `protected` / `private` inheritance is conceptually the same as  `protected` / `private` composition (from an access point of view).  Code outside the class is unable to access anything `protected` / `private`  in the class.  ie `protected` / `private` means does not exists to outside code.

Comment: @Peter Why would they have undefined behavior? C-style upcasts are perfectly well defined, they have the same function as an upcast with ```static_cast```, the only difference being that they ignore access specifiers. You can access the casted pointer just fine. The compiler has to (and will) generate the appropriate pointer adjustments, if needed.

Answer (score 2):

> what actually is inaccessible?

The standard talks about "the class itself being accessible/inaccessible" at a certain point, as can be seen from the following quoted statements. And if the base class `B` of `N` satisfies the given condition(s) for being called accessible at `R` then the standard specifies that there are some properties associated with such a class like implicitly converting a pointer to a derived class to a pointer to that base class.

From [class.access.base#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.access.base#4):

> A **base class `B` of `N` is accessible** at `R`, if
>
> - an invented public member of B would be a public member of N, or
> - R occurs in a member or friend of class N, and an invented public member of B would be a private or protected member of N, or
> - R occurs in a member or friend of a class P derived from N, and an invented public member of B would be a private or protected member of P, or
> - there exists a class S such that B is a base class of S accessible at R and S is a base class of N accessible at R.

From [class.access.bae#5]:

> If a **base class is accessible**, one can implicitly convert a pointer to a derived class to a pointer to that base class ([conv.ptr], [conv.mem]).

(emphasis mine)

And since none of the condition mentioned for a class to be called accessible base class are satisfied in your example, `X` is not an accessible base class of `Y`. Meaning the standard does not allow an implicit conversion from a `Y*` to `X*`.

---

##### Summary

In effect, standards specifies condition(s) for a base class to be called accessible and if those condition are satisfied then it(the standard) says that there are some things possible with that class. If on the other hand, the condition are not satisfied in the first place, then those special things like derived to base conversion isn't possible.